# how can I locate site web.config in an IIS virtual folder instead of site root

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I have multiple instances of an ASP.NET web application that are identical in every way except for the web.config file, which contains the instance-specific settings.  In order to avoid having multiple copies of the same set of files, I want to place all or part of the web.config file in an **IIS** virtual folder.

I created an IIS virtual folder "config" under the site root folder and used the following line in the web.config file to refer to it:

```
<appSettings configSource="config\\app.config" />
```

Unfortunately, IIS looks for a physical path under the site root folder named "config", and coughs up an error when it can't find it.

Does anyone know a way to trick IIS into using the **IIS** virtual folder? I am also open any suggestions (including server-side code) on how to accomplish the same goal (using the same folder to serve multiple instances of the same web site differing only by appSettings).

I have also considered dumping all the content into a virtual "web" folder, but this would require re-basing all references in nearly 200 files.  Using the  tag is not a viable solution here because it re-bases everything including same page references, yet inexplicably does not work for references to .less files.

*Edit: while the idea is to use the same folder for multiple instances, I want to make it clear that each instance would be set up in IIS as a separate web site/application.  It's just that each instance would point to the same physical folder.*

Comment: No need to put it in another folder. If I understand your current setup correctly the `app.config` could still live in the root along side the `web.config`. I normal name it `_app.config` and have the `<appSettings file="_app.config">` in the `web.config` file. Same thing for connection strings ie `_ConnectionStrings.config` and `<connectionStrings configSource="_ConnectionStrings.config" />`

Comment: @Nkosi As stated in my post, each instance of the application requires its own app.config file, so the location of the app.config file either needs to be virtualized via IIS or somehow needs to be programmatically altered based on the request url in the server-side code.  Apparently the IIS route can't be done, so I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this via server-side code.

Comment: Ok now I understand.

Comment: How about creating a folder in `App_Data`. lets say `App_Data/config` and in that folder you would have file based on a convention. something like the site/application like sitex.json or .config or .xml or some id that you map per site {guid}.config....in your code you can then load file based on incoming request. If you don't want the file in the root config you could do a folder per site `App_Data/sitex/app.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing more research, I found a workable solution to this.  It is true that a *direct* reference using configSource to another config file in a virtual folder is not possible because folder references in web.config files are expected to be physical references.  However, IIS virtual directories can each have their *own* web.config files.  My solution is:

1) Create a virtual folder under your site in IIS.  Point it to whatever physical path you want.

2) Add a web.config file to that folder containing the contents specific to that instance of your site.  From the example in my original post, that would be the appSettings section.

3) In your server-side code, use the `System.Xml.XPath` methods to iterate through the web.config file using the path returned by `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("config/web.config")`.  MapPath converts the IIS virtual folder relative reference to a usable physical reference on the server.

Using web.config in the virtual folder has another benefit in that it will be invisible to client browsers, just as the site web.config is.

Using the above method, the same binaries and client viewable files can be used from one source physical location to serve multiple IIS instances of the same site differing only by the contents of the web.config file stored in the "config" IIS virtual folder.  Obviously, each instance of the application in IIS would point its config virtual folder to a different physical location with its own web.config file.

I have tested this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Virtual directory is an IIS concept, but the config file redirection you use (separate config file) is a .NET/ASP.NET concept. Thus, when the separate config file is being discovered, only physical directories are searched, because the searching algorithm has no idea what is virtual directories and how to find them in IIS configuration.

Comment: Ok, if using IIS the virtual folder for config redirection won't work, then is there a trick that I can use in the server-side C#.NET code to accomplish the same goal using physical paths?  For example, is there a way to do something like this:

    `if(Request.Url.ToString().Contains("foo"))`  
         `... get appSettings from d:\foo\app.config`  
    `else`  
         `... get appSettings from d:\bar\app.config`

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer until and unless someone has a way to do this either via manipulating IIS or via server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try Web config transformation for multiple environments. I have given a sample link to start up

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100

Comment: The link is working or Google "Web config transformation tutorials"

Comment: I read through the article and while I think this is a very useful tool for development purposes, I can't see how it would solve my problem.  Based on my read of the article, the net result is still one web.config file and multiple sets of binaries.  I'm looking for a solution that allows me to "swap in" the appropriate appSettings section via C# code based on the url.  If that is not possible, then I'll likely have to create a custom config file unrelated to web.config as suggested by @Nkosi